# Pasting text into web browser C#

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to paste some text into a web browser element. For example:

```cs
private void pasteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    WebBrowser1.PasteString("some text");
}
```

PasteString() Clearly doesnt exist but you get what i mean.

I have just tried pasting the string outright with a button, but the browser loses focues before it pastes.

I have tried many thing but none of them work.
Anything would help, i just wanna paste a string into a textbox on a website with a button, or something alike.

Comment: Are you using the WebBrowser Class from System.Window.Forms?

Comment: @EduBic Yes, right from the toolbar

Comment: I think you can get the Document from the WebBrowser object and then use the HtmlDocument.GetElementById(String) method to get the HTML input element, in the returned HtmlElement object put your string.

Comment: @EduBic Thank you! I will check this out, do you have an example of this? If you dont its fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

**N.B.** not tested

```
private void pasteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    var elemWithFocus = WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement;
    elemWithFocus.SetAttribute("value", theStringToPaste);
}
```

Comment: How would you get the input element? Im not so good at this.

Comment: CTRL+ALT+I in the Chrome Browser with that page loaded in order to inspect the page

Comment: I mean like in C#. Lets say i go into a page and sellect a textbox and press paste it should get the id of the textbox that was latest in focus. Or something like that u know what i mean?

Comment: @EduBix if its even possible...

Comment: THANK YOU MAN. This really helped

Comment: What if we are NOT using the webBrowser control but off-shelf browser like Chrome